# Why am I still getting an Error CS0236 (Field Initializer error)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I followed this other stack overflow discussion on how to get a random integer from a minimum value to a maximum value but it doesn't seem to work correctly in my code:

```
Random r = new Random();
int posx = r.Next(1, 816);
private void BtnTeleport_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BtnTeleport.Location = new Point(LblMiss.Location.X+posx, 5);
}
```

but it gives me the error:

> A field initializer cannot reference non static field, method, property 'Form1.r'

any clues as to why it does this?

Comment: Because of this → `int posx = r.Next(1, 1000);` Consider reading [Compiler Error CS0236](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0236). *If you are trying to initialize a variable outside a method, consider performing the initialization inside the class constructor*

Comment: how do i fix it then @RezaAghaei

Comment: The `Random` class should be initialized in `Form1` constructor or use `static` modifier to initialize it, then you can access the instance.

Comment: @MurtUjjaiwnwal Read the first comment again, starting with `consider`.

Answer (score 0):

To move those setting codes into the method:

```
private void BtnTeleport_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e){Random r = new Random();int posx = r.Next(1, 816);BtnTeleport.Location = new Point(LblMiss.Location.X+posx, 5);}
```

Comment: Initializing the `Random` instance within that method is almost certainly *not* the right approach. There should almost certainly be a single instance for the lifetime of the object. Whether `posx` needs to be determined on each invocation is a different matter. (I'd also strongly recommend that you format the code you've presented so that it's readable without scrolling.)